# Creating a pattern of irregular shapes in Illustrator like the default WhatsApp background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, patterns

I'd like to take a collection of shapes and distribute them into another shape in Illustrator to get the effect similar to the WhatsApp background.

[image: Whatsapp]

I could swear I saw a video or article from Adobe about a new feature that allows this but this would have been years ago. I quite vividly remember them taking the letter 'A' and filling it with vectors of animals, and in the options for this effect you could let Illustrator slightly warp them to fit together better.

Comment: No illustrator has no such feature. Doing good packing is actually quite hard. But try svgnest

Comment: Maybe ask [this kid](https://www.boredpanda.com/doodle-boy-decorates-restaurant-joe-whale) - ([video](https://youtu.be/O4PHM19bgus))

Comment: There is a plug-in for Illustrator from Astute Graphics (no affiliation-costs money but has a free trial) called collider scribe- part of that is a plug-in called "space fill" that will fill an object with one or many other objects- there are plenty of you tube videos from them about this